# Apache Virtual Host not working on .com domain

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, virtualhost

I have got a strange problem.

I have two domains: mysite.co.uk and mysite.com, which need to point to the same directory on my server. The VHost for mysite.co.uk works perfectly. However, mysite.com will not work.

When I re-start apache I see no errors. When I enter the domain, it is reaching the correct server but showing me the index file in **/var/www**, instead of re-directing to **/var/www/html/mysite.co.uk/web/**

Is there an error with my code? It is EXACTLY the same as what appears on the configuration for mysite.co.uk, so I am very confused as to why it is not working properly.

Sites Available:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mysite.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysite.co.uk/web/
ServerAlias *mysite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName *.mysite.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/mysite.co.uk/web/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this with a single vhost entry as long as the content you want displayed on both URL's is in the same folder on the server.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mysite.com
ServerAlias mysite.co.uk *.mysite.co.uk *.mysite.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysite.co.uk/web/
</VirtualHost>
```

You may also be getting betrayed by a default vhost if you have setup your new ones in a seperate file.

If your running Ubuntu (Or some other distro's) you can use 'apache2ctl -D DUMP_VHOSTS' from the command line to show what ServerNames are being accepted and what config file:line they are in.

Note - this does not list address added on ServerAlias lines

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should be using wildcards in your second `ServerName` directive (in Apache.conf), try replacing it with www for the moment, while leaving the wildcard aliases in Sites Available, if you have more than one mysite.com subdomain the server will respond to.

Comment: Ok, I just tried that but no luck. What logs should I be looking at for any potential errors?

Comment: Can you change one more thing? I think the `ServerAlias` in Sites Available should probably be *.mysite.com, you may not see errors, as it isn't wrong, just not right for what you want..

Comment: Ok I have got it working on www.mysite.com. I was having an issue with test.mysite.com, but I have changed the mx record of www.mysite.com to point at the new server and the vHost seems to work. However, test.mysite.com is still not working so I guess its a subdomain issue? - Apologies for not mentioning that in my question

Comment: It may be a DNS issue, you need to make sure that test is either a CNAME or an A record, and that record now points to the new server.

Comment: Good suggestion but I dont think that is the issue because test.mysite.com does actually reach the correct server. It just lands in the incorrect directory (/var/www) instead of (/var/www/html/mysite.co.uk/web)

Comment: First try and add the `ServerAlias` directive to apache.conf also, possibly both with just test.example.com, just to ensure the Alias matches exactly..